# GLib-GIO-ERROR**: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system

Tags: c, gtk, mingw, gtk3

Unfortunately, I am using Windows (Windows7 x64).
With MinGW compiler in Code::Blocks and GTK+3.6.4.
I compiled manually all the schemas from glib.

---

When I use File Chooser dialogue / colorpicker - it doesn't matter,
I am getting the following error:
`GLib-GIO-ERROR**: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system` and the program terminates.

---

What do I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 17):

GSettings looks at the compiled schemas in the directories pointed by the `$XDG_DATA_DIR` environment variable. You can either use a launcher script that sets up the environment for you, or you can rely on the prefix, and install the gschemas.compiled files in the `share/glib-2.0/schemas` directory under the same prefix as your app binary is, e.g. if you have the following layout:

```
YourApp/
  bin/
    YourApp.exe
  lib/
    libgtk3.dll
    libgobject.dll
    …
  share/
    …
    glib-2.0/
      schemas/
```

Make sure that the `gschemas.compiled` file is under `YourApp/share/glib-2.0/schemas`, and that the `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml` is there as well.

Comment: I never understood exactly the thing with that variable. Is this system environment variable that I can set from Advanced System Settings with the name `XDG_DATA_DIR` and the value of `D:\apps\gtk\share\glib-2.0\schemas` Also I am aiming to compile my programs statically.

Comment: The `XDG_DATA_DIR` environment variable is a colon-separated list of directories, in decreasing order of preference, used to compute paths for files — see: http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: As an aside: GLib and GTK+ do not like much being statically compiled, as they have, or depend, on various run-time loadable modules. You can tweak the loading paths for most of them. In this case, though, loading a file has no bearing to static or dynamic linking. It's a location for ancillary files, and you can use environment variables to handle relocatability.

Comment: Might sound insolent.. but I see that you have enough knowledge to help. Do you have any free time to help by Team Viewer. I will keep one in mind for returning the favor. RETURN_SUCCESS

Comment: +1. This fixed it for me, and probably answers the question, though it's not marked as such (and was derailed).

Comment: @DeltaProxy XDG_DATA_DIRS should not include the `\share\glib-2.0\schemas` part, i.e. only `D:\apps\gtk` in your case.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is with the Glib schemas that apparently are not compiled on your system.

You need the `glib-compile-schemas` and find the `glib-2.0/schemas` directory which is located in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`, I don't know if it will be found in the same path within MinGW, but I don't see why it wouldn't, so you must execute the following command<sup>1</sup>

```
glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
```

and that will create a file `gschemas.compiled` so you need write permission, then the error will go away.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Provided that the GLib schemas are installed in that directory.</sub>

Comment: Because I am stuck to Windows so as many other users. By the way, I've already mentioned that I have compiled them successfully.. though they are already compiled in the bundle anyway (i.e `gschemas.compiled` already exists)

Comment: Delete it an recompile it, or search for the `.gschema.xml` file corresponding to the missing `schema` and check if it was compiled successfuly or if it was compiled at all.

Comment: Well I tried with two different `gschemas.compiled` the first, that is compiled by default (as a bundle's 3rd party dependent) and the other, compiled manually by me. Though.. I needed to use `intl.dll` from gtk2's bin, because it didn't exist and that caused crash when using `gsettings`. On the other hand I have no idea of what checking you mind.

Comment: Not compiled, or simply not copied into the executable's redistributable folder (along with DLLs, icons, themes, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this issue from the following documentation as below
https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html
following environment variable to the share folders similar to below in my case

XDG_DATA_DIRS : D:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\share