# Ubuntu meld: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system

Tags: ubuntu, settings, gnome, meld

This is a vanilla Ubuntu **16.04** LTS, based on [Xubuntu core](http://xubuntu.org/news/introducing-xubuntu-core/) to be exactly. So I need to install packages myself. All went well except `meld`, on starting which, I'll get:

```
(meld:4188): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system

[2]+  Trace/breakpoint trap
```

I've found three existing answers, none of them is working for my case.

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/266788/gnome-terminal-issue

Following the suggestions, I've done reinstalling `gsettings-desktop-schemas`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gsettings-desktop-schemas
```

- [GLib-GIO-ERROR**: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953925/glib-gio-error-no-gsettings-schemas-are-installed-on-the-system)
  Following the suggestions,

  - I've done `glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` and
  - I've made sure the correct gschema.xml is there
  - and I've also tried to sets up the `$XDG_DATA_DIR` environment for meld.

However, none of them is working.

```
  $ ls -l /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml   
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5354 2016-03-24 16:46 /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml

$ XDG_DATA_DIR=/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/ meld ...
(meld:4326): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system

[2]+  Trace/breakpoint trap
```

- [meld - GLib-GIO-ERROR**: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784566/meld-glib-gio-error-no-gsettings-schemas-are-installed-on-the-system)

I've consult this one as well, however, that's Redhat 6.3 server environment, and the OP was installing each component to its own prefix; thus he ran into errors like this. In other words, his case doesn't apply to my vanilla Ubuntu.

I've run out of options. 
Please help.

Thanks

```
$ gsettings list-recursively
No schemas installed

$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

$ uname -rm
4.4.0-21-generic x86_64

$ apt-cache policy meld gsettings-desktop-schemas
meld:
  Installed: 3.14.2-1
  Candidate: 3.14.2-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.14.2-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
gsettings-desktop-schemas:
  Installed: 3.18.1-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.18.1-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.18.1-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Possibly related, the command `gsettings list-recursively` gives me the error `No schemas installed`. Do you get the same error?

Comment: To what value did you set XDG_DATA_DIR?

Comment: From old logfiles I see that I used to have `XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/` while nowadays I have `XDG_DATA_DIRS=:/var/lib/snapd/desktop`. I do not configure this variable myself.

Comment: THANKS!! That works! Please "answer" so that I can "accept". More details -- after more investigation, I realized it is most probably a **XUbuntu Core** *specific* issue, because I have another system that I installed via net-install, and there is no issue with meld, even without the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` environment variable. Since I'm installing everything the same on both systems, the natural conclusion I have is that it is a XUbuntu Core specific issue.

Comment: The old setting work, for me, XUbuntu 16.04 LTS, the nowadays setting of `XDG_DATA_DIRS=:/var/lib/snapd/desktop` doesn't, FYI.

Comment: Yes, my `gsettings list-recursively` returns `No schemas installed` too.

Comment: @JonasBerlin,  I'm having exactly the same problem as yours, even my `XDG_DATA_DIRS` is `:/var/lib/snapd/desktop` as well. Please "answer" so that I can "accept". I'll wait for 2 days before I put in the "answer" myself. BTW, the simplest solution I found is `unset XDG_DATA_DIRS`.

Comment: Yeah that seems to work too. The `snapd` that is the new black in XDG_DATA_DIRS seems to be related to Snappy Ubuntu Core (http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/snappy)

Comment: This whole thing seems to be just another case of "crazy people that don't use defaults are shooting themselves in the foot anyway" mentality :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From post comments: Try setting:

```
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
```

This seems to be the old behaviour in Ubuntu 15.10. On closer inspection, it seems the "old value" is nowadays set in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/55gnome-session_gnomerc` only if the session (in env var `$STARTUP`) matches the pattern `gnome-session*`. I have a `~/.xsession` style startup so that's why it does not match for me. I guess Xubuntu might likewise have `$STARTUP` set to something not matching the pattern.

This all is possible to fine-tune through `~/.xessionrc` which is sourced from `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/40x11-common_xsessionrc`. So you can just put the `XDG_DATA_DIRS` setting shown at the top of this answer in `~/.xsessionrc` and the wanted value will get installed regardless of the session type. There you can also override what type of session you want etc. The files in /etc/X11/Xsession.d/ are all loaded (sourced) in alphabetically ascending order.

Comment: Oh, I start my X the old fasion way -- boot to text and `startx`, into WM (`fluxbox`), not a desktop. Maybe that's why. BTW, again, the simplest solution I found is unset XDG_DATA_DIRS, somewhere in profile.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I suspect it might still run those scripts I mentioned.. But yeah, good!

Comment: Actually, no, `startx` uses `~/..Xclients` instead. That's why I never put my profile customization in either `~/..Xclients` or `~/.xessionrc/`.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed similar problem by setting
`GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas`

Comment: This also solves the issue for when running an executable built from source using the gtk-osx project.